# each attachment I need to attach pdf or word or jpg icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

in driveFiles I am getting multiple file names.
for each attachment I need to attach pdf  or word or jpg icon
so I used substr and lastIndexOf got the file formats.
now using if conditions I am able to disable icon for one files.
if I test for more than one files, its not checking for second `if`.
I think the problem is due to the return statement in first `if`.
can you tell me how to fix it for multiple files?

```
{this.props.driveFiles.length > 0 ? 
  this.props.driveFiles.map(_driveFileKey => {
    var driveFormat = _driveFileKey.name.substr(
      _driveFileKey.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1
    );
    console.log("filename--->", driveFormat);
    if (driveFormat === "pdf") {
      return (
        <div>
          {" "}
          <Icon icon={["fal", "file-pdf"]} />
          {_driveFileKey.name}
        </div>
      );
    } else if (driveFormat === "doc") {
      return (
        <div>
          {" "}
          <Icon icon={["fal", "file-word"]} />
          {_driveFileKey.name}
        </div>
      );
    } else if (driveFormat === "jpg") {
      return (
        <div>
          {" "}
          <Icon icon={["fal", "file-image"]} />
          {_driveFileKey.name}
        </div>
      );
    }

    //return <div>{_driveFileKey.name}</div>;
  })
: ""}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Problem

Curly brackets in JSX (`{}`) are limited in functionality in that they only support a [*single* expression](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx). Think of an expression as a block of code that would be evaluated by an interpreter/compiler as a single line of code. Fitting such complex logic in a single expression is both hard to implement and to read.

### Solution

Use JSX expressions in conjunction with other useful React/Javascript features. The solution below is written in ES6 (Let me know if you need it transpiled down to ES5).

Import `Icon` from the appropriate file or define it in this file. You can fill in the rest of your components in the `render` function.

The logic is split into functions that make it easier to understand what the code is trying to achieve. Test it out and see if it works for you.

There are also notes below explaining some snippets.

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Icon from '...<icon directory>...';

class IconExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.getIconInfo = this.getIconInfo.bind(this);
    this.getIcons = this.getIcons.bind(this);
  }

  getIcons(driveFiles) {
    return driveFiles.map((driveFileKey, i) => {
      const dotIndex = driveFileKey.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1;
      const driveFormat = driveFileKey.name.substr(dotIndex);
      console.log('filename---> %s', driveFormat);
      const iconInfo = this.getIconInfo(driveFormat);
      if (iconInfo === null) {
        return null;
      }
      return (
        <div key={`${driveFormat}${i}`}>
          <Icon icon={iconInfo} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  getIconInfo(fileExtension) {
    const iconInfo = ['fal'];

    if (fileExtension === 'pdf') {
      iconInfo.push('file-pdf');
      return iconInfo;
    } else if (fileExtension === 'doc') {
      iconInfo.push('file-doc');
      return iconInfo;
    } else if (fileExtension === 'jpg') {
      iconInfo.push('file-jpg');
      return iconInfo;
    }

    return null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.props.driveFiles.length > 0 &&
        this.getIcons(this.props.driveFiles)
        }
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

IconExample.propTypes = {
  driveFiles: PropTypes.array,
};

export default IconExample;
```

### Notes

#### Expression Evaluation

```js
{this.state.driveFiles.length > 0 &&
this.getIcons(this.state.driveFiles)
}
```

The `&&` (and) operator evaluates the statements on both sides and returns the *last* statement, the one on the right. Thus `this.getIcons(this.props.driveFiles)` will only be evaluated if `this.state.driveFiles.length > 0` returns true.

#### Keys

```
<div key={${driveFormat}${i}}>
  <Icon icon={iconInfo} />
</div>
```

[This part](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) of the React docs explain why we use keys when returning from iterators.

#### Binding in Constructor

```js
this.getIconInfo = this.getIconInfo.bind(this);
this.getIcons = this.getIcons.bind(this);
```

This is an issue with using "classic" javascript functions, but I believe in the most modern ECMAScript and above you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_arrow_function_expression_(%3E)) in class definitions to obviate the need. We bind to ensure what `this` would refer to in the function, and we want that to be the component we are using, not the global `this` or whatever would be the default in this case.

Comment: I strongly disagree using state where you don't have to. Not only there is no need to keep state but now you have the problem when `this.props.driveFiles` change you have to keep state in sync. The icons **will** re-render if the props change ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a variable to store your icons?
Something like this:

```
const icons = {
  pdf: ["fal", "file-pdf"],
  doc: ["fal", "file-word"],
  jpg: ["fal", "file-image"],
};
```

Then you can use reduce instead of map to only render valid files:

```
{
  this.props.driveFiles.length > 0 ?
    this.props.driveFiles.reduce((result, _driveFileKey) => {
      var driveFormat = _driveFileKey.name.substr(
        _driveFileKey.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1
      );
      console.log("filename--->", driveFormat);
      if (icons[driveFormat]) {
        result.push(
          <div>
            {" "}
            <Icon icon={icons[driveFormat]} />
            {_driveFileKey.name}
          </div>
        );
      }
      return result;
    }, [])
    : ""
}
```

If you wan to support another file type just add it to the icons variable. Like: `png: ["fal", "file-image"]`

I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/joseluismurillorios/pen/ZgyLMg?editors=0010) showing this example